# Loop Through LINQ Results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have this code that works fine in one project, but in another project I'm getting this error, and cannot figure out why. All I did was copy the code from one project to the other:

```
Dim query = From row In dtTDAF_Payments
    Group row By GL_Account = row.Field(Of String)("GL_Account") Into GLGroup = Group
    Select New With {
        Key GL_Account,
        .Amount = GLGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Amount"))}

For Each x In query
```

So the error is 'x' is not defined... but as I mentioned, it works in the other project fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps the options (e.g. "option strict") are different between the two projects?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with LINQ.  It would happen looping through a simple array or any other list too.

In the project that works, either `Option Infer` is turned on, or `Option Explicit` is turned off.  In the project that does not work, `Option Infer` is off and `Option Explicit` is on.

Alternatively, it could be that the `x` variable is declared somewhere else in the code which isn't obvious.  If that were the case, then in Visual Studio you could find it by right clicking on `x` and choosing to go to the definition of it.  If it's defined elsewhere in the project, it'd jump you to it.  If it isn't, then it'd just jump you to the `For Each x` line.

Comment: Or possibly the project that works already contains a declaration of something called `x`.

Comment: True.  I may be assuming to much.  I'll update my answer